# Query about $ Windows. ~ TMP

Tags: windows

I have a question regarding Windows Temp on one of the client computers.

The problem is that we have a 120GB SSD and it is divided into 2 partitions - one 53GB and the other 57GB.

However, on the first 53GB partition, we only have 3 GB of free space.
The second partition is practically empty - there's just the $ Windows folder there. ~ TMP which takes up 3GB.

I would love to delete this folder to merge both partitions into one, because I need it for disk cloning.

Can I delete this $ Windows. ~ TMP ?

Comment: What's your question? How to remove the partition so there's one 120GB drive? What files can be moved to the 57GB partition? How to clone the drive as-is?

Comment: The question is can I delete this $ Windows. ~ TMP folder to be able to merge both partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a folder of this specific name on any Windows machine. There are lots of temp folders and Windows folder, but not by that name.

Connect a USB drive to the machine.

Copy the folder to the USB drive and make sure the copy succeeds.   Delete the folder.

If you cannot do this, the folder may be busy, so then restart in Safe Mode and try the same thing.

If the folder or files in it have lost their locking handle, you may be able to delete in Safe Mode or another Windows User.

Try the easy steps first.